# Save file in document directory with relative path?

Tags: ios, objective-c

is there any way to save file in document directory with relative path?

I have tried something like this but its not working

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"22.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:@"../../Documents/22.png" atomically:true];
```

Comment: try this : ${SRCROOT}/Documents/22.png

Comment: @KKRocks No its not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the URL to the documents folder from `NSFileManager`

```
NSString *fileName = @"22.png"
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
NSURL *documentsURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
                                                             inDomain:NSUserDomainMask 
                                                    appropriateForURL:nil 
                                                               create:NO
                                                                error:nil];
NSURL *fileURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToURL:fileURL atomically:true];
```

Comment: I know this function.. but I want to get document directory in relative path way... It will change runtime

Comment: In a standard app (not jailbroken) that's not possible. Since the URL can change you have to use the `NSFileManager` (or the outdated `NSSearchPaths...`) method every time.